using grep with a variable containing xml-tags
I have a script that is trying to find a line in a text file. It could be completely alphanumerical, but it's also possible that it contains special characters, mostly < and > as it's sometimes xml-tags with content.
Basically this is what I am trying to do:
$ grep '<Tag>20240605074212800000001' filename | less
        <Tag>Detlef</Tag>
[user@servername /path]
$ STRANGEBEHAVIOR="'<Tag>Detlef'"
[user@servername /path]
$ echo $STRANGEBEHAVIOR
'<Tag>Detlef'
[user@servername /path]
$ grep $STRANGEBEHAVIOR filename | less
(END)
[user@servername /path]
$ grep "$STRANGEBEHAVIOR" filename | less
(END)
[user@servername /path]
$ echo "grep $STRANGEBEHAVIOR filename | less"
grep '<Tag>Detlef' filename | less

I had found out that using grep the next thing works, but using zgrep it does not:
[user@servername /path]
$ STRANGEBEHAVIOR="<Tag>Detlef"
[user@servername /path]
$ echo $STRANGEBEHAVIOR
<Tag>Detlef
[user@servername /path]
$ grep "$STRANGEBEHAVIOR" filename | less
        <Tag>Detlef</Tag>

For reasons I do not understand, I can't find an easy solution. If I manually type my search with single quotes, grep works the way I understand it to, it looks for this string and ignores all special characters. If I give grep the same information using a variable, grep does not find a match, probably because it is interpreting the single quotes as part of the string, but why?

STRANGEBEHAVIOR="'<Tag>Detlef'" means the single quotes are part of the variable
Therefore when running grep "$STRANGEBEHAVIOR" filename the command will receive 2 parameters: '<Tag>Detlef' and filename. Since there's no string containing '<Tag>Detlef', no match was printed
zgrep OTOH passes most of the arguments to grep, and technically it should pass the whole pattern argument as-is to the exec* family or similar calls, i.e. the final grep also receives '<Tag>Detlef' if you use the first method. However many zgrep implementations are some simple scripts that don't pass the arguments properly. If they do some simple grep $pattern then the $pattern will undergo word-splitting then the final argument grep receives will not contain single quotes anymore

Sorry, i don't understand that. Yes, the single quotes are part of the variable content. I want them to be. They way i understand it, bash will simply replace "$STRANGEBEHAVIOR" with 'Detlef' and then do a grep 'Detlef' filename the same way i would if i typed just that. If that's not what is happening, what do i have to do so that grep will not treat < and > as part of a pipeline commend and instead simply as part of a pattern string?

@Broetchenholer The shell parses quotes before expanding variables, so if you put quotes in a variable, by the time they're expanded into the command, it's too late for them to do anything useful; they're just treated as data rather than shell syntax. See "Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?", "Setting an argument with bash", and many many other questions from people who've tried to do this. tl;dr quotes go around data, not in data.
